# Como transferir um array em Javascript para array em PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Como posso transferir um array em JavaScript para um array em PHP ?

Função JavaScript

array de datas de vencimento (datasvenc) no arquivo cadastro_contratos.php:

```
 function calculamensalidades(){
  var datasvenc = new Array(7);
  var tabela;
  tabela = "<br><table border='0' width='30%' style='text-align:center'><tr><td bgcolor='#4682B4'>Parcela</td><td bgcolor='#4682B4' >Valor</td><td bgcolor='#4682B4'>Vencimento</td></tr>";


  for(var a=0; a<document.getElementById("select_parcelas").value; a++)
 {
  var n_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), eval(a+mesvencimento), diavencimento);
  var diavenc = date.getDate();
  var mesvenc = n_date.getMonth()+1;
  var anovenc = n_date.getFullYear();
     tabela = tabela + "<tr><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>"+(a+1)+"</td><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>R$ "+valorparcela.toFixed(2)+"</td><td bgcolor='#9AC0CD'>"+diavenc+"/"+mesvenc+"/"+anovenc+"</td></tr>";
     datasvenc[a] = diavenc+"/"+mesvenc+"/"+anovenc;
 }
}
```

Preciso inserir para cada registro da tabela a data de vencimento correta no mesmo arquivo cadastro_contratos.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
  $dataVencimento = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'datasvenc');
  $dataVencimento = unserialize(base64_decode($dataVencimento));//Decode para array
    for($numparcelas=1; $numparcelas <= $parcelas; $numparcelas++ ){
          $cadastraparcelas = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO t_cadparcelas (NumContrato, NumParcela, ValorParcela, DataVencimento, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
          $cadastraparcelas->execute(array($IDultimocontrato, $numparcelas, $valorparc, $dataVencimento[1], $status));
      }
```

...

Comment: Pode usar `JSON.stringify(array)` no JS e `json_decode($_GET['array'], true);` no PHP, já testou?

Comment: olá @Sergio obrigado pelo retorno, nunca testei, pode postar algum exemplo que possa utilizar com meu código acima? obrigado novamente

Comment: A resposta que dei era o que procurava?

Comment: @Sergio ajudou, mas simplemente passei a variavel javascript para um input e logo depois tratei a string de datas em php para inserção no banco, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor maneira de passar dados entre cliente e servidor é JSON.

Assim para codificar/converter uma array em JSON, ou num formato que as funções criadas para interpretar JSON possam usar é:

No lado do cliente (JavaScript):

```
JSON.stringify(<conteudo>); // para enviar (converter em string)
JSON.parse(<conteudo>);     // para receber (converter em Tipo)
```

No lado do servidor (PHP):

```
json_encode(<conteudo>);           // para enviar (converter em string)
json_decode(<conteudo>[, true]);   // para receber (converter em array ou objeto dependendo do segundo parametro)
```

Assim no seu código poderia fazer:

```
var dadosParaPHP = JSON.stringify(datasvenc);
```

e no lado do PHP fazer:

```
$dadosDoJavascript = json_decode($dataVencimento, true);
```